# Reflecting a point over a line

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, reflection

I am working with my son on a math question:

Triangle $DUC$ with coordinates $D(-3,-1), U(-1,8)$, and $C(8,6)$.  After reflecting $U$ over $DC$ prove that the resulting shape $DUCU'$ is a square.

In the answer they jump to the fact that $U' = (6-3)$ , I'm not seeing how that is a given?  Please explain

Comment: Don't you mean "after reflecting $U$ over $DC$" instead of $U'$. That is $U'$ is the reflection of $U$ over $DC$?

Comment: Hint: it's enough to show that $\triangle UDC$ is an isosceles right triangle.

Comment: Fixed the U' issue.

Comment: The proofs I see are showing U' = (6,-3) then showing the distance formula for the four sides, what I am asking is how they get to 6,-3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that

$$
U C=\sqrt{9^2+2^2}=\sqrt{85}=\sqrt{2^2+9^2}=UD
$$
Therefore the mid-point $M$ of $DC$ is the perpendicular foot from $U$ to $CD$ i.e. $UM \perp CD$.

$$M= \left(\frac{-3+8}{2}, \frac{-1+6}{2}\right)=\left(\frac{5}{2}, \frac{5}{2}\right)$$
Let $U’(a,b)$ be the reflectional image of $U$ on $CD$, then $M$ is also the mid-point of $UU’$, hence
$$
\left\{\begin{array} { l } 
{ \frac { - 1 + a } { 2 } = \frac { 5 } { 2 } } \\
{ \frac { 8 + b } { 2 } = \frac { 5 } { 2 } }
\end{array} \Rightarrow \left\{\begin{array}{l}
a=6 \\
b=-3
\end{array}\right.\right.
$$
Hence $U’=(6,-3)$.

$$ \textrm{  Diagram for reference }$$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the midpoint of $CD$ is also the midpoint of $UU'$ (*why?*).

[image]